# "This movie format is not supported" error on old iPhones

Tags: iphone, video, ipod, mpmovieplayer

I've recently upgraded my app to retinal display. The app includes movie files (m4v). In the past week I've received a few emails that say they've received "This movie format is not supported" errors, but I can't seem to track down the common factor, and I can't replicate it.

- The original movies were 480x320, the new movies are 960x640.
- I believe the same settings were used for both sets of movies: m4v, h2.64
- They work fine on my iPod 3G (iOS4.3), iPad 1 (iOS4.3), iPhone 4
- They work fine on all simulators down to iOS 3.0.
- The first error to come in was on an iPhone 2G, but later I received one from iPod 3 (iOS4.2)

Most people have had no problems, still getting great reviews.

Hypothesis:
I'm thinking it just has to do with low memory on older phones + double size movies, but I can't be sure without testing, and since most people aren't having problems I'm reluctant to downgrade the app.

Anyone else encounter this? Any ideas?

If anyone's got a 2G or early 3G phone I'd be happy to toss out a promo code or two if you'll help me to test this through. Thanks.

-k.

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone 2g does not play my video encoded with h.264 that works fine on ALL other browsers either. Seems likes it could be the old phone technology as the problem.